# Application of Bezout's theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let we have $p_1q_2 -p_2q_1 = \pm 1$ where $p_1,p_2,q_1,q_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and let $\cfrac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then, how can we show that there are integers $x,y$ such that $$xp_1+yp_2=a, xq_1+yq_2=b.$$

Using linear algebra we can deduce the result by putting $p_i,q_j$'s inside a $2\times 2$ matrix. Is there any other way to prove it?

Comment: $3×5-2×7=1$ and $\frac11\in\mathbb Q$, but no integers $x, y$ satisfy $5x=1,\ 12y=1$.

Comment: I think it's a typo, it may be $xp_1+yp_2=a, xq_1+yq_2=b$. And the answer will be trivial, as you say you can find it using linear algebra easily, this also mean the solution can be converted to simple algebra, like $ q_2 (xp_1+yp_2)- p_2(xq_1+yq_2)=q_2 a- p_2 b \longrightarrow x=q_2 a- p_2 b$

Comment: My bad, I edited the question as above.

Comment: Use the theory of Farey Sequences.

Answer (score 0):

So, $\gcd(p_1,p_2)=1$, hence the set $\{p_1x+p_2y\mid x,y \in\mathbb{Z}\} =\mathbb{Z}$.
So there is $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p_1x+p_2y=a$.
Others goes similar ways